# How do I construct do_install for a Yocto recipe, to ensure debian packages are copied from the deploy debs folder to ${D}

Tags: debian, embedded-linux, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I have a simple Yocto recipe that fetches code from repositories on a server using ssh, invokes a makefile that builds a library called 'libcustom.a', copies the library to /usr/lib in the working directory ${B}/git, before finally attempting to add the debian packages to the destination directory ${D}. The last step is where I have an issue.

The recipe <my_custom>-lib invokes the following tasks - line #37 in 'do_install' refers:

```
SUMMARY = "bitbake-layers recipe"
DESCRIPTION = "Creating a debian package for a custom library"
PRIORITY = "optional"
SECTION = "examples"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = 
"file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}-${PV}:"

SRC_URI = "git://<server>:/opt/Eagle-Proj/Custom_lib;protocol=ssh;branch=master"
SRCREV = "c5aa799664abc189639e07cd284a0adcf4c282ed"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

FILES_${PN} = "custom-lib-*.deb"
FILES_${PN} = "${B}${bindir}/*"
FILES_${PN} = "${B}${libdir}/*"
#FILES_${PN} = "${D}${bindir}/*"
#FILES_${PN} = "${D}${libdir}/*"

do_compile() {
    make CC="${CC}" AR="${AR}" lib
}

do_install() {
    install -d ${B}${libdir}
    install -m 0644 ${S}/build/arm/lib/libcustom.a ${B}${libdir}
    #install -D ${WORKDIR}/deploy-debs/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4/<my_custom>-lib-*.deb ${D}
    #note: commented out line above is line #37
}
```

My layers structure is as follows:

[image]

The 'fetch' and subsequent make are not the issue, so SRC_URI and SRCREV configured correctly. Please note that I have changed some paths/file names to avoid disclosing company/product info. Thus <my_custom>-lib is essentially the recipe/package name.
After a clean, if I build the recipe using bitbake by **excluding** line #37, calling it sequence #2, the following tasks are invoked, typically.

```
do_deploy_source_date_epoch_setscene (90181): log.do_deploy_source_date_epoch_setscene.90181
do_populate_lic_setscene (90180): log.do_populate_lic_setscene.90180
do_fetch (90197): log.do_fetch.90197
do_unpack (90201): log.do_unpack.90201
do_prepare_recipe_sysroot (90202): log.do_prepare_recipe_sysroot.90202
do_patch (90222): log.do_patch.90222
do_configure (90230): log.do_configure.90230
do_compile (90234): log.do_compile.90234
do_install (90309): log.do_install.90309
do_package (90319): log.do_package.90319
do_populate_sysroot (90320): log.do_populate_sysroot.90320
do_packagedata (90401): log.do_packagedata.90401
do_package_write_deb (90489): log.do_package_write_deb.90489
do_package_qa (90490): log.do_package_qa.90490
```

The generated custom library is located in the following folder:
<my_workspace>/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/<my_custom>-lib/0.1-r0/git/build/arm/lib/libcustom.a

The custom library is copied to the /usr/lib/ folder as follows:
<my_workspace>/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/<my_custom>-lib/0.1-r0/git/usr/lib/libcustom.a

The debian packages have been created in the deploy_debs folder off the working directory ${B}  i.e.
<my_workspace>/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/<my_custom>-lib/0.1-r0/deploy-debs/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4/, is populated as expected:

```
<my_custom>-lib-dbg_0.1-r0.233_armhf.deb
<my_custom>-lib-dev_0.1-r0.233_armhf.deb
```

So far so good.

Now, the intended purpose of line #37 is to ensure that debian packages end up in the following folders:

```
./image/<my_custom>-lib-dbg_0.1-r0.81_armhf.deb
./image/<my_custom>-lib-dev_0.1-r0.81_armhf.deb
./package/<my_custom>-lib-dbg_0.1-r0.81_armhf.deb
./package/<my_custom>-lib-dev_0.1-r0.81_armhf.deb
./deploy-debs/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4/<my_custom>-lib-dbg_0.1-r0.82_armhf.deb
./deploy-debs/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4/<my_custom>-lib-dev_0.1-r0.82_armhf.deb
./packages-split/<my_custom>-lib/<my_custom>-lib-dbg_0.1-r0.81_armhf.deb
./packages-split/<my_custom>-lib/<my_custom>-lib-dev_0.1-r0.81_armhf.deb
```

If initially I build the recipe after a clean, with line #37 **included**, the sequence of tasks invoked, call it sequence #1, is as follows:

```
do_deploy_source_date_epoch_setscene (91243): log.do_deploy_source_date_epoch_setscene.91243
do_populate_lic_setscene (91242): log.do_populate_lic_setscene.91242
do_fetch (91259): log.do_fetch.91259
do_unpack (91263): log.do_unpack.91263
do_prepare_recipe_sysroot (91264): log.do_prepare_recipe_sysroot.91264
do_patch (91285): log.do_patch.91285
do_configure (91292): log.do_configure.91292
do_compile (91296): log.do_compile.91296
do_install (91373): log.do_install.91373
```

Sequence #1 fails on the 'do_install' and I get the following error:

```
DEBUG: Executing shell function do_install
| install: cannot stat '<my_workspace>/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux- 
gnueabi/<my_custom>-lib/0.1-r0/deploy-debs/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4/<my_custom>-lib-*.deb': No 
such file or directory
```

For sequence #1, because the command line #37 is attempting a copy of <my_custom>-lib-*.deb from the deploy-debs folder, the error appears to occur because Yocto is clever enough to check for the existence of the 'deploy-debs' folder and files however it is too early in the process, for what I'm trying to achieve. As we've seen in sequence #2, one of the tasks writes the debian files to the 'deploy-debs' folder in the first place, which doesn't occur in sequence #1. Intuitively, one would assume the task that achieves this to be 'do_package_write_deb' .

Assume I do two runs. I **first** build the recipe with line #37 excluded (sequence #2), before editing the recipe and **re-including** line #37 (sequence #3) and re-invoking the build *without* doing a clean between the two sequences. I don't quite understand how the debian files end up in the package, image and package-split folders after executing sequence #3 however the files **are** present.

For a *different* run, therefore, sequence #2 executes the following:

```
do_deploy_source_date_epoch_setscene (101280): log.do_deploy_source_date_epoch_setscene.101280
do_fetch (101296): log.do_fetch.101296
do_unpack (101300): log.do_unpack.101300
do_prepare_recipe_sysroot (101301): log.do_prepare_recipe_sysroot.101301
do_patch (101325): log.do_patch.101325
do_configure (101329): log.do_configure.101329
do_compile (101333): log.do_compile.101333
do_install (101405): log.do_install.101405
do_populate_sysroot (101416): log.do_populate_sysroot.101416
do_package (101415): log.do_package.101415
do_packagedata (101497): log.do_packagedata.101497
do_package_write_deb (101585): log.do_package_write_deb.101585
do_package_qa (101586): log.do_package_qa.101586
```

With the 'deploy-debs' folder having been created after sequence #2 is run, sequence #3 adds the following additional tasks to the 'log.task_order' file:

```
do_compile (102023): log.do_compile.102023
do_install (102036): log.do_install.102036
do_populate_sysroot (102048): log.do_populate_sysroot.102048
do_package (102047): log.do_package.102047
do_packagedata (102129): log.do_packagedata.102129
do_package_write_deb (102217): log.do_package_write_deb.102217
do_package_qa (102218): log.do_package_qa.102218
```

I noticed the following in log.do_package_write_deb.102217:

```
DEBUG: Preparing tree <my_workspace>/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux- 
gnueabi/<my_custom>-lib/0.1-r0/**deploy-debs** for packaging at <my_workspace>/tmp- 
glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/<my_custom>-lib/0.1-r0/sstate-build- 
package_write_deb/deploy-debs
```

I have tried experimenting by creating my own tasks to see if I could influence the sequence executed but without success.

```
 do_after_install() {
     install -D ${WORKDIR}/deploy-debs/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4/<my_custom>-lib-*.deb ${D}
 }
 
 addtask after_install after do_install before do_package
```

In actual fact, there must be a simpler way to achieve the correct result without having to resort to the above. I suspect that #37 is not correct and needs to be replaced. How do I create the debian packages? I have googled extensively but can't find any useful examples that relate to what I'm trying to do.

I am a relative novice at Yocto, so I would appreciate help on this. Many thanks in advance and apologies for there being so much detail however I think it's all relevant.

Comment: The reason is that you only have a .a so it ends up in <my_custom>-lib-staticdev which is the package you need to install. However, why do you need a static library on the target ?

Comment: @AlexandreBelloni  I will be adding additional recipes to the image that have a dependency on the static library but I agree that it may not be required for the target. But my issue remains that when building the image <my_custom>-image-dev, the error "Package <my_custom>-lib is not available" persists because the debian package is only being created in the deploy-debs folder and is not being added to ${D} i.e. the image folder etc.

Comment: This is not your issue, the issue is that <my_custom>-lib is not generated because it is empty and that you should use <my_custom>-lib-staticdev instead.

Comment: @AlexandreBelloni  I have subsequently also added header files, in addition to the static library i.e. "install -d ${D}${includedir}/<some_folder>" and "install -m 0644 ${S}/include/<some_folder>/* ${D}${includedir}/<some_folder>".  I guess a similar question is being asked here, where a static library only is being added:  https://www.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2015-September/026695.html

Comment: Where are the earlier comments?  Why have they been removed?

Comment: The headers will end up in <my_custom>-lib-dev. I believe you need to read a bit about the PACKAGES and FILES variables. You could also probably benefit from a training

Comment: From the yoctoproject docs, it seems to confirm that I have only managed the intermediary step in the build process that has resulted in the Package Feeding, as illustrated in this diagram.
https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#package-feeds-dev-environment
What appears to be missing is the next step described under the heading 3.5.4. Package splitting.
https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#package-splitting-dev-environment

Comment: Due to the files now being added, adding the following variables eliminates FILES warnings: FILES_${PN} = "<my_custom>-lib-*.deb"
FILES_${PN} = "${libdir}/*"
FILES_${PN} = "${includedir}/*"
To prevent 'Package '<my_custom>-lib' has no installation candidate' errors, I've added a PACKAGE variable, along with some runtime settings:   PACKAGES = "${PN} ${PN}-dev ${PN}-dbg ${PN}-staticdev"
RDEPENDS_${PN}-staticdev = ""
RDEPENDS_${PN}-dev = ""
RDEPENDS_${PN}-dbg = ""  This still doesn't resolve the issue though.

Comment: Section 4.2.23 here https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/structure.html#build-tmp-work-tunearch-recipename-version outlines what should be in each sub-folder off ${WORKDIR}.  Section "Debugging Packaging" here http://www.ibeeto.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Yocto_DevDay_Advanced_Class_Portland-User-Space-RJS.pdf says the same thing.

Comment: Aligned with the code in 'do_install' therefore, the generated folders and files in ${libdir} and ${includedir} are present in ${WORKDIR}/image, ${WORKDIR}/package and ${WORKDIR}/packages-split. In addition, the static library is added to ${WORKDIR}/packages-split/<my_custom>-lib-staticdev/${libdir}. This does seem correct, in terms of the 3.5.4 diagram. The question is, when "fully packaged", would you expect the debian packages to be present in ${WORKDIR}/image, ${WORKDIR}/package and ${WORKDIR}/packages-split, not just in the ${WORKDIR}/deploy-debs folder and how does one achieve this?

Comment: You don't, as explained before, you must NOT install the debian package in ${WORKDIR}/packages-split. ${WORKDIR}/packages-split is the content of the debian package. The debian package can't be inside itself.

Comment: Hi @AlexandreBelloni Thanks for your good advice. Much appreciated.  I have reverted my previous changes i.e. the recipe for <my_custom>-lib is doing a 'do_compile' only. This means that the static library is not packaged but is in the 'git' folder only. A separate recipe <my_custom>-net, which creates a binary executable, is dependent on the static library and and header files of <my_custom>-lib.  Only the binary executable of <my_custom>-net is now being packaged, which I have verified after flashing the target.

Comment: Is there a way of ensuring the static library of <my_custom>-lib is written to 'rootfs' so that it can be accessed by <my_custom>-net, without having to package the output generated by <my_custom>-lib?  Using 'bitbake -e <my_custom>-image-dev | grep ^IMAGE_ROOTFS=' shows that it is located in the work area i.e. '/tmp-glibc/work/stm32mp13_disco-ostl-linux-gnueabi/<my_custom>-image-dev/1.0-r0/rootfs'. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I get you as a static library should not be installed on the target, you don't need it there.

Comment: @AlexandreBelloni  I probably mean how do you get the static library for <my_custom>-lib into 'tmp-glibc/sysroots-components' so that it can be accessed by <my_custom>-net or any other recipe?

Comment: Simply have <my_custom>-net depend on <my_custom>-lib, this will put your static libraries in the sysroot for <my_custom>-net as long as your library is in install in ${D}/${libdir}/ by the <my_custom>-lib recipes